# Sending BEP20 Token with ethers.js

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I'm getting error while sending BEP20 Token using ethers.js.

```
TypeError: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="value", value={ "hex": "0x8b4d", "type": "BigNumber" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.9.2)
    at makeError (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:122:21)
    at assert (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:149:15)
    at assertArgument (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:161:5)
    at getBigInt (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/maths.js:96:36)
    at set gasLimit [as gasLimit] (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/transaction/transaction.js:330:69)
    at Transaction.from (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/transaction/transaction.js:670:29)
    at Wallet.sendTransaction (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/abstract-signer.js:184:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async send (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:228:20)
    at async Proxy.transfer (project/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:261:16) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x8b4d', _isBigNumber: true },
  shortMessage: 'invalid BigNumberish value'
}
```

As per ethers.js documentation, I used wallet and Contract to send tokens to another account like this.

```js
const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545");

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(walletPrivate);
const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider);

const erc20_rw = new ethers.Contract(process.env.TOKEN_ADDRESS, require('./tokenAbi.json'), connectedWallet);

const tx = await erc20_rw.transfer(recieverAddress, ethers.parseUnits('10', 18));
await tx.wait();
```

- I did tried by passing amount manually.
- I did installed BN.js library to convert numbers to BigNumber.
- I searched alot.

Comment: One thing you can check is the data type and format of the `ethers.parseUnits('10', 18)` result. Make sure it's a valid BigNumber. You can try logging the value before passing it to the `transfer` method to see if it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ethers.parseUnits('10', 18)`, You should try `ethers.parseEther('10')`.
It will parse your amount to ethers using 18 decimals.

Learn more on [ethers Documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/getting-started/#starting-contracts)

*Bonus tip*

You can directly add provide to wallet while declaration.

```js
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(walletPrivate, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

error message indicates the transfer amount:

```
erc20_rw.transfer(recieverAddress, ethers.parseUnits('10', 18))
```

instead of relying on 3rd party tools, you could you use javascript BigInt arithmetic

```
const amount = 10n * 10n ** 18n
```

`10n`: This is a BigInt literal representing the number 10.

`10n ** 18n`: This is 10 raised to the power of 18, where the ** operator denotes exponentiation in JavaScript. The result is a BigInt representing a very large number, specifically 10 followed by 18 zeros.

then pass the amount to the function

```
erc20_rw.transfer(recieverAddress,amount)
```

Comment: Problem persists.